# why the square bracket next to another square bracket is considered one single character?

Tags: perl

```
my $str = "[[SELECT * FROM Personnel]]";

print substr($str, 0, 1); #that return [[ not [
print substr($str, 1, 6); #that return SELECT
```

Take the two square bracket like only one, this is my html return example:

```
[[SELECT
```

`[[` is the first print. That is wrong must be only one `[`.
`SELECT` is the second print

Comment: [U+301A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/301a/index.htm)?

Comment: Add newlines to the ends of both of your `print` statements. I think you'll find that your interpretation of the situation is wrong.

Comment: I put a letter in the middle of the two symbols and functions, but as the functionality of the code is that logic that the two symbols need to be together, just to make the substr takes two symbols as if they were one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I run into these problems, I break the problem down and ensure I have ways to see where each part of the output comes from. My process through this particular problem would have gone something like this:

First, get rid of parts of the program until I stop seeing the problem. Once I've done that, I've probably found the point that's causing the problem since it's the bit I just removed. I would have removed the second output statement. Here I use Perl 5.10's `say` which appends a newline automatically:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.10;

my $str = "[[SELECT * FROM Personnel]]";

say substr($str, 0, 1); #that return [[ not [
```

If I run that, I see that it's not that output statement that's giving the doubled `]`.

Now I put the next bit of code back and keep doing that until I see the problem again. I know that I removed the problem and got closer to the problem, but now it's time to zero in on the statement that causes it.

In this case, I have two output statements together that show the problem. I want to see what output comes from each statement. Adding some text around the output and numbering the strings can show me which statement did what:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.10;

my $str = "[[SELECT * FROM Personnel]]";

say "1. <" . substr($str, 0, 1) . ">"; 
say "2. <" . substr($str, 1, 6) . ">";
```

Now I see what each `say` did:

```
 1. <[>
 2. <[SELEC>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first print statement only prints `[`, you just can't see it because you are not printing a newline. Your second print statement outputs `[SELECT` which is expected from your inputs to `substr`:

```
my $str = "[[SELECT * FROM Personnel]]";

print substr($str, 0, 1),"\n";
print substr($str, 1, 6),"\n";
```

output:

```
[
[SELEC
```